# C# Create Instance of Color from any supported Format (Win.Forms Properties -> Color)

Tags: c#, colors, parsing

What is the best way to instantiate a new Color from any supported value, like for example
"FF00FF11" or "Gray" or "234,255,65"? I need to generalize maximum as possible this implementation, but can't find a way to do it.

With System.Reflaction I can get the value for enumerator KnownColor, but how can I distinct this "FF00FF11" from this "Gray"?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx).

I'm not sure it'll help you with your last example ("234,255,65"), however. You might have to try to parse that first (`String.Split()`, `Int32.TryParse()`, `Color.FromArgb()`) and if it fails, use the above.

Answer (score 1):

When we need to do this we used the TypeConverter. The static function I used was:

```
    private static System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter colorConv = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse a string to a Color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="txt"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static System.Drawing.Color ColorFromString(string txt)
    {
        try
        {
            object tmp = colorConv.ConvertFromString(txt);
            return (tmp is System.Drawing.Color) ? (System.Drawing.Color)tmp : System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
        }
        catch 
        {
            // Failed To Parse String
            return System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
        }
    }
```

This works for two of your cases but fails on the Hex one. You could add some logic to try to parse the Hex one first.